# How to write text to a text file only if not already written

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to add text to a text file only if the text doesn't already exist in the text file. My implementation below adds text even if it already exists. How can I fix my implementation to only add new non-existent items?

My implementation so far:

```
WriteToFile::WriteToFile(QString data)
{
    path += "C:/Data.txt";
    QFile file(path);
    if ( file.open(QFile::Append) )
    {
        QTextStream in (&file);
        QString line;
        do {
            line = in.readAll();
            qDebug() << in.readLine();

            if (!line.contains(data)) {
                QTextStream stream( &file );

                data += "\r\n";

                stream << data << endl;
            }
        } while (!line.isNull());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will either have to:

- parse the entire file and extract all paths from it or
- keep track of all paths written to a file to avoid parsing it again and again

From there is it simple, just create a `QSet<QString> writtenSoFar`, and for every path, check if the set contains it, if so skip writing, if not, write it and append it to the set. In the first case, you will have to write the parsed paths into the set just to make a single check, wildly inefficient, just like the parsing itself. So better keep track of the paths as you go.

The set is important to give you good lookup performance. It is quite fast, since it is hash based, it is essentially a value-less `QHash`.